# Validate Email in Entry widget content more than once - tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, validation, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have a code that correctly validates email, but this happens only once. So if the email is invalid, it wont let me validate it again. Is there a way how to validate it over and over?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import re

class Test(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry("{}x{}+250+150".format(500, 500))
        
        self.entry()

    def testAlphaValue(self, value):
        if value.isalpha():
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def testEmail(self, email):
        regex = '^[a-z0-9]+[\._]?[a-z0-9]+[@]\w+[.]\w{2,3}$'
        wdg = self.wdgLst
        if(re.search(regex, email)):
            return wdg.configure(text='Email is valid')    
        else:
            return wdg.configure(text='Email is invalid')

    def entry(self):
        self.formFrame = LabelFrame(self.root, bg='grey', bd=1)
        self.formFrame.place(x=50, y=50, width=400, height=400)

        regEmail = self.root.register(self.testEmail)
        regAlpha = self.root.register(self.testAlphaValue)

        nameEnt = Entry(self.formFrame)
        nameEnt.config(validate="key", validatecommand=(regAlpha, '%S')) 
        nameEnt.grid(row=0, column=1)

        emailEnt = Entry(self.formFrame)
        emailEnt.config(validate="focusout", validatecommand=(regEmail, '%P'))
        emailEnt.grid(row=0, column=0)
        emailLbl = Label(self.formFrame, text='Email', font=("Helvetica", 8))
        emailLbl.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.wdgLst = emailLbl

root=tk.Tk()
test = Test(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why does your code create 2 entry widgets if you just need to check one email input?

Comment: @PSSolanki Well since email's entry validate option is 'focusout' I needed some other entry widget to click in so the testEmail function is called. Thats all.

Comment: Alright. Looks like I'm getting closer to a solution :)

Comment: I have found a working solution and i'm writing an answer fir ya :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working code for ya which validates email on `focus-out event` (as you wanted) - (must read the reason with explanation below the code)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import re

class Test(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry("{}x{}+250+150".format(500, 500))
        
        self.entry()

    def testAlphaValue(self, value):
        if value.isalpha():
            return True
        else:
            return False
        
    def checkEmail(self, val):
        if re.search(regex, val):
            self.wdgLst.configure(text='Email is valid')
            return True
        else:
            self.wdgLst.configure(text='Email is Invalid')
            return False

    def entry(self):
        self.formFrame = LabelFrame(self.root, bg='grey', bd=1)
        self.formFrame.place(x=50, y=50, width=400, height=400)

        regEmail = self.root.register(self.checkEmail)
        regAlpha = self.root.register(self.testAlphaValue)

        nameEnt = Entry(self.formFrame)
        nameEnt.config(validate="key", validatecommand=(regAlpha, '%S')) 
        nameEnt.grid(row=0, column=1)

        emailEnt = Entry(self.formFrame)
        emailEnt.config(validate="focusout", validatecommand=(regEmail, '%P'))
        emailEnt.grid(row=0, column=0)
        emailLbl = Label(self.formFrame, text='Email', font=("Helvetica", 8))
        emailLbl.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.wdgLst = emailLbl

root=tk.Tk()
regex = '^[a-z0-9]+[\._]?[a-z0-9]+[@]\w+[.]\w{2,3}$'
test = Test(root)
root.mainloop()
```

***REASON FOR THE ISSUE ***

From what I got to know about the issue, there seems to be a rule which is::

```
The function registered to the validate command must return either True or False.
In any other case, if the function returns something else,  
it DISABLES the validation for the respected widget.
```

In your code you were making it return `wdg.configure(<something here>)` which was disabling the validation right after the first run.

You can also use the method suggested by @ShaneLoyd above if you wish to change your approach but if you just want to stick to validate commands, go with the above code.

Comment: This works just as I wanted to. Thank you for your time! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain why your code doesn't work except that perhaps the Entry widget must only allow the validate code to run once. This might work for your needs.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import re


class Test(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry("{}x{}+250+150".format(500, 500))

        self.entry()

    def testAlphaValue(self, value):
        if value.isalpha():
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def testEmail(self, sv):
        email = sv.get()
        regex = '^[a-z0-9]+[\._]?[a-z0-9]+[@]\w+[.]\w{2,3}$'
        wdg = self.wdgLst
        if (re.search(regex, email)):
            return wdg.configure(text='Email is valid')
        else:
            return wdg.configure(text='Email is invalid')

    def entry(self):
        self.formFrame = LabelFrame(self.root, bg='grey', bd=1)
        self.formFrame.place(x=50, y=50, width=400, height=400)

        sv_email = StringVar()
        sv_email.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode,
                                   sv=sv_email: self.testEmail(sv_email))
        regAlpha = self.root.register(self.testAlphaValue)

        nameEnt = Entry(self.formFrame)
        nameEnt.config(validate="key", validatecommand=(regAlpha, '%S'))
        nameEnt.grid(row=0, column=1)

        emailEnt = Entry(self.formFrame)
        emailEnt.config(textvariable=sv_email)
        emailEnt.grid(row=0, column=0)
        emailLbl = Label(self.formFrame, text='Email', font=("Helvetica", 8))
        emailLbl.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.wdgLst = emailLbl


root = tk.Tk()
test = Test(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The reason why the OP's code didn't work was because he was unintentionally disabling the validation right after the first run, because the validation function must return either True or False. In every other case it gets disabled for the respected widget.

Comment: Yeah it works. The only problem I have is that the message 'email is (in)valid' appears immediatly after I start writing. Anyway thank you!